# Error while deploying my Django App in Vercel

Tags: django, deployment, vercel

So My Django app runs perfectly fine on the local server, i've been trying to upload it on vercel but it keeps giving me this error.

***Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [35 lines of output]
/tmp/pip-build-env-xx4e_y5y/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`***

I've tried locating the setup.cfg file, but i couldn't find any. This is my first deployment, and i don't know how to deploy it yet properly. Any help regarding what the error is and how to solve it, is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you are getting an error while installing some packages/dependencies from `requirements.txt`. Can you please share a few more lines from `traceback`?